# Need help on personal portfolio project

Tags: html, css

So on this one challenge I keep getting the error: "The height of the welcome section should be equal to the height of the viewport." I have 100vh on it but im not sure how to fix it.

html:

```
<header>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <a href="#welcome-section" id="logo-link">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav-list">

      <a href="#projects">
        <li>Projects</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#profile">
        <li>Profile</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#contact">
        <li>Contact</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<!--BODY-->

<body>
  <section id="welcome-section">
    <div class="header-text">
      <h1><code>Hello World!</code></h1>
      <p>My name is Nick</p>
    </div>
  </section>
```

css:

```
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #007cc7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 5;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: cyan;
}

#logo-link {
  color: white;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#welcome-section {
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #12232e;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #203647;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.header-text {
  margin: auto;
}

#welcome-section h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

#welcome-section p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

Link to the challenge: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/responsive-web-design-projects/build-a-personal-portfolio-webpage

Comment: what is the issue you are facing??

Comment: The border of `#welcome-section` is preventing the test to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working Demo:** https://dojo.telerik.com/EkoCUneS/2

You need to add

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Remove `margin-top` from `#welcome-section`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}   
    
#navbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #007cc7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 5;
}

.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.nav-list a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: cyan;
}

#logo-link {
  color: white;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#welcome-section {
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #12232e;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #203647;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.header-text {
  margin: auto;
}

#welcome-section h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

#welcome-section p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav id="navbar">
    <a href="#welcome-section" id="logo-link">
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </a>

    <ul class="nav-list">

      <a href="#projects">
        <li>Projects</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#profile">
        <li>Profile</li>
      </a>
      <a href="#contact">
        <li>Contact</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<!--BODY-->

<body>
  <section id="welcome-section">
    <div class="header-text">
      <h1><code>Hello World!</code></h1>
      <p>My name is Nick</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```